# Spring Junit Hibernate @Transactional - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, junit

I find a lot of people get this exception, but cannot find 
why this happen with me :). How could it be 
within `@Transactional` method, when 
I refer to object loaded from db within same method?

The entity should not be detached, and session should be same ... but this not works.

I have a lazily initiated property in my object, and when try to 
read from it, Hibernate states "no session", but what lead to close it? As I understand hibernate session should be alive inside `@Transactional` method until it done.

I tried to mark `@Transactional` my `@Test` method and it works.

But I would like to have few `@Transactional` methods calls within one test method,because I have to save entities and load them in separate sessions. This is because I use `@OrderBy` and it works only if object loaded from DataBase.

Here test class:

```
@Test
public void getOpenTest() {
    ...
    Advertisement closedAdvertisement = closeAdvertisement(initialAdvertisement.getId());
    ...
}

//this method inside same test class
@Transactional
private Advertisement closeAdvertisement(Long id){
    Advertisement advertisement = advertisementRepository.findOne(id);

    //*** CRASHES HERE ***
    //The method is @Transactional. Why session closed here?
    advertisement.getStatusChronology().get(0);

    ...
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AdvertisementRepository  extends CrudRepository<Advertisement, Long> {
    //Simple request just to load entity 
    @Query("select ad  "
            + " from Advertisement ad")
    public List<Advertisement>getOpen();
}
```

Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement")
public class Advertisement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "advertisement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("updated DESC")
    List<Status> statusChronology;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "statusChronology")  
    private Advertisement advertisement;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_open")
    private Boolean isOpen;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private LocalDateTime updated;  

    ...
}
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: web.scraper.database.model.Advertisement.statusChronology, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    ...
    at web.scraper.database.repository.AdvertisementRepositoryTest.closeAdvertisement(AdvertisementRepositoryTest.java:80)
    at web.scraper.database.repository.AdvertisementRepositoryTest.getOpenTest(AdvertisementRepositoryTest.java:107)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Transactional` doesn't work on private methods.